# update object value by matching id within a deeply nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested

I have this Javascript object:

```
{
  title: "Securities Finance Trade Entry",
  children: [
    {
      containerType: "Tabs",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Common",
          children: [
            {
              containerType: "Row", 
              children: [
                {
                  input: "ComboBox",
                  label: "Trade Type",                  
                  options: ["Repo", "Buy/Sell", "FeeBased"],
                  value: "FeeBased"
                },
                {
                  input: "ComboBox",
                  label: "Direction",
                  options: ["Loan", "Borrow"],
                  value: "Borrow"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              containerType: "Row",
              children: [
                {
                  containerType: "Column",
                  children: [
                    {
                      containerType: "Row",
                      children: [
                        {
                          input: "Text",
                          label: "Book",
                      value: "test"
                        },
                        {
                          input: "Text",
                          label: "Counterparty",
                      value: "test"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      containerType: "Row",
                      children: [
                        {
                          input: "Date",
                          label: "StartDate",
                      value: "10/02/2021"
                        },
                        {
                          input: "Date",
                          label: "EndDate",
                      value: "10/02/2021"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      containerType: "Row",
                      children: [
                        {
                          input: "Text",
                          label: "Security",
                      value: "test"
                        },
                        {
                          input: "Numeric",
                          label: "Quantity",
                      value: "test"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

given a specific label I need to find the object with that label and then replace the value, the issue I have is that this format could be more nested and I cant look at any specific level, I need to look at all objects at all levels then just replace the value in the one where the label matches.  I have tried recursion but can't get it to work, please can anyone advise?

EDIT:

This is my attempt but it fails badly :)

```
    const deepReplace = (obj, id, value) => {        
        if  (obj.children) {
            obj = obj.children.map((childObj) => {              
                if (typeof childObj === "object") {
                   deepReplace(childObj, id, value)
                }
            })
            return obj;
        };                
        if (obj.label === id) {
          obj['value'] = value;
          return obj
        };
     };

const newObj = deepReplace(myObj, 'TradeType', 'Repo')
```

Comment: please add your code as well what goes wrong?

Comment: please add a typical call of the function. what are you searching?

Comment: Do you want to mutate the object, or do you want to create a new object and leave the input unchanged?

Comment: Your `map` callback has no return value. Your `map()` result is assigned to `obj` (and then returned) but is an array. Your `if` statements have no `else` case where they return anything.

Comment: want to create a new object and leave the existing unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be a good candidate for [recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/). Since we have to do a repeated operation multiple times and we are not sure how many.

1. *Base case*: **if label is there and is same as required then change the value**
2. If label does not exist or is not same then check if the property *children* exists and then iterate over it and repeat 1 and 2.

```js
// passed (obj, "Book", "changed")
const replaceValueOfTheLabel = (obj, label, value) => {
  if (obj.label === label) {
    return obj.value = value;
  }

  if (obj.children)
    for (const ob of obj.children) {
      replaceValueOfTheLabel(ob, label, value)
    }

}

const obj = {
  title: "Securities Finance Trade Entry",
  children: [{
    containerType: "Tabs",
    children: [{
      title: "Common",
      children: [{
          containerType: "Row",
          children: [{
              input: "ComboBox",
              label: "Trade Type",
              options: ["Repo", "Buy/Sell", "FeeBased"],
              value: "FeeBased"
            },
            {
              input: "ComboBox",
              label: "Direction",
              options: ["Loan", "Borrow"],
              value: "Borrow"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          containerType: "Row",
          children: [{
            containerType: "Column",
            children: [{
                containerType: "Row",
                children: [{
                    input: "Text",
                    label: "Book",
                    value: "test"
                  },
                  {
                    input: "Text",
                    label: "Counterparty",
                    value: "test"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                containerType: "Row",
                children: [{
                    input: "Date",
                    label: "StartDate",
                    value: "10/02/2021"
                  },
                  {
                    input: "Date",
                    label: "EndDate",
                    value: "10/02/2021"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                containerType: "Row",
                children: [{
                    input: "Text",
                    label: "Security",
                    value: "test"
                  },
                  {
                    input: "Numeric",
                    label: "Quantity",
                    value: "test"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}

replaceValueOfTheLabel(obj, "Book", "changed");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in an answer that doesn't mutate your original data but returns a copy with the appropriate values replaced, it might look like this:

```js
const deepReplace = (label, value) => (obj) => Object (obj) === obj
  ? { ... obj, 
      ... (obj .label == label ? {value} : {}), 
      ... (obj .children ? {children: obj .children .map (deepReplace (label, value))} : {})
    }
  : obj

const input = {title: "Securities Finance Trade Entry", children: [{containerType: "Tabs", children: [{title: "Common", children: [{containerType: "Row", children: [{input: "ComboBox", label: "Trade Type", options: ["Repo", "Buy/Sell", "FeeBased"], value: "FeeBased"}, {input: "ComboBox", label: "Direction", options: ["Loan", "Borrow"], value: "Borrow"}]}, {containerType: "Row", children: [{containerType: "Column", children: [{containerType: "Row", children: [{input: "Text", label: "Book", value: "test"}, {input: "Text", label: "Counterparty", value: "test"}]}, {containerType: "Row", children: [{input: "Date", label: "StartDate", value: "10/02/2021"}, {input: "Date", label: "EndDate", value: "10/02/2021"}]}, {containerType: "Row", children: [{input: "Text", label: "Security", value: "test"}, {input: "Numeric", label: "Quantity", value: "test"}]}]}]}]}]}]}

console .log (deepReplace ('Counterparty', '*** New value ***') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We test if our input is an object.  If not, we simply return it.  If it is, we create a new object by including all the root properties of the object, replacing a `value` property if we have the right `label`, and then recurring on the `children` nodes.

There are all sorts of benefits to immutable data.  I would recommend adopting it when you can.

### Update: Code Explanation

A comment suggested that this was challenging to read.  Here's my attempt to explain it.

```js
const deepReplace = (label, value) => (obj) => /* ... */
```

First, we curry the function, passing `label` and `value` to get back another function that takes `obj` and returns an object with the change made.  This is useful both internally (we later will pass a reference to `deepReplace (label, value)` to `map`) and externally, as we can now just pass the label and value and get a function we can apply to many different objects.

We then begin a conditional operator (ternary).  We test whether the input parameter is an object, using `Object (obj) === obj`.  There are many ways to test this, including `typeof` and calling `Object.prototype.toString()` on the value.  I find this one quite robust.

If it is not an object, then we hit the last line `: obj`, and return the original value.  If it is an object, we return an object created out of three steps:

```js
    ... obj,
```

Here we just spread the original object into our new one.  This is a form of shallow cloning.

```js
    ... (obj .label == label ? {value} : {}),
```

Here we test if the object's `label` property matches our target.  If it does, we spread `{value}`, which is modern shorthand for `{value: value}` into our object.  If it doesn't, we spread an empty object, thereby adding no properties.

```js
    ... (obj .children ? {children: obj .children .map (deepReplace (label, value))} : {})
```

And here, we handle `children`.  If our node has no `children` property, we spread an empty object.  If it does, we `map` a recursive call to the same function over them, and spread in an object whose `children` property is the result.  Here the currying helps, as we can just call `map (deepReplace (label, value))`  If our function looked like `deepReplace = (label, value, obj) => /* ... */`, then here we would have to call `map ((item) => deepReplace (label, value, item))`.  It's not a big deal, but this way feels cleaner.

So in older JS, we might have written the equivalent code like this:

```js
const deepReplace = (label, value) => (obj) => {
  if (Object (obj) !== obj) {
    return obj
  }

  const newObject = {...obj}

  if (obj .label == label) {
    newObject .value = value
  }

  if ('children' in obj) {
    newObject .children = obj .children .map (deepReplace (label, value))
  }
  return newObject
}
```

That would have been essentially equivalent.  I find the newer syntax more enlightening, but either would work.

---

We probably should have handled the array case, and that would add a little bit to the implementation, and an (untested) version might look like this:

```js
const deepReplace = (label, value) => (obj) => Array .isArray (obj)
  ? obj .map (deepReplace (label, value)) 
  : Object (obj) === obj
    ? { ... obj, 
        ... (obj .label == label ? {value} : {}), 
        ... (obj .children ? {children: obj .children .map (deepReplace (label, value))} : {})
      }
    : obj
```

Here we check for an array first, and if so, `map` the results, as we do for `children`.

Comment: Updated with a longish explanation